# Toggle individual item inside datalist with jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am displaying Title from the database using datalist with it's content hidden.When each item is clicked I want to display it's hidden content.I am using jquery for this.This is what I tried so far.

Datalist

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dl_news" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label class="ntitle" runat="server"   Text='<%#Eval("title")%>'>  </asp:Label> </br>
     <asp:Label class="ncontent" runat="server"  style=" display:none; " Text ='<%#Eval("ncontent")%>'>  </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

  </asp:DataList>
```

This is  jquery

```
 $(".ntitle").click(function () {

         $(".ncontent").hide(); // first hide all
         $(this).next(".ncontent").slideDown("fast");
    });
```

Please HELP!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".ntitle").click(function () {

         $(".ncontent").hide(); // first hide all
         $(this).parent().find(".ncontent").slideDown("fast");
    });
```